# i am trying to pass one variable from one python file to another python file

Tags: python

> sample_box.py

```
gr=0

class SampBoxLayout(BoxLayout):

    def input_rpm(self, instance, value):
        if value is True:
            global gr
            gr=22
```

> pyth.py

```
from sample_box import gr

while(True):
    if(gr== '22'):
```

Comment: You're trying to pass a variable from one file to another. And?

Comment: when i run pyth.py file then whole sample_box.py file run  because i imported that file,i want to pass gr variable without running the sample_box file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass variable between python scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048237/pass-variable-between-python-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a constant instead of a normal variable:

```
GR = 0
```

and then import it:

```
import sample_box
```

To get the constant, use the syntax:

```
sample_box.GR
```

Add this to your code to prevent the import statement to run sample_box.py:

```
GR = 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # all your code that you don't want to run here
```

Comment: im actually creating gui using kivy and for communication purpose i want some variable like gr and my app file is sample_box.py , so when i import sample_box into the pyth.py file it launches that because of the import i don't want that i want to just pass gr variable