# Sending variable to another script Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

How can I send one variable to another script? I have 3 scripts (`bot.py`, `language_dict.py`, `markups.py`)

`language_dict.py` (dictionary)

```
russian = {
       "section": "Выберите раздел ➡",
       "individual": "Физические лица",
       "legal_entity": "Юридические лица",
   }
```

In `bot.py` I declare this dictionary to `dic` variable

```
import language_dict

def language(message):
chat_id = message.chat.id
if message.text == "Русский":
    dic = language_dict.russian
    msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, dictionary["section"])
```

So, I need to send `dic` to `markups.py`

```
import bot

#to here
```

Comment: What do you mean *"send"*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass variable between python scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048237/pass-variable-between-python-scripts)

Comment: If those scripts are different processes, [any IPC method will do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: jonrsharpe, I mean "pass"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this.

```
#in bot.py 
def class1():
    def func1(self):
        #do something
        #dic = language_dict.russian
        return #dic

#in markups.py
#from bot.py import class1
#create object of class1 under main method 
class1_obj = class1()
dic = class1.func1()
```

Answer (score -1):

You are assigning `dic` as a local variable in your `language()` method.

To fix this just assign `dic` above your `language()` method like this:

```
dic = {}

def language(message):
    global dic
    ...
```

you also need to put `global dic` in your method so that the interpreter knows you are changing the global variable `dic` inside your method

Comment: I tried it, didn't work. bot.py passed empty dictionary